# How can I importing npm packages that do not export modules with awesome-typescript-loader?

Tags: typescript, npm

I am trying to use webpack awesome-typescript-loader to bundle my project, but am having trouble with a couple modules that don't export themselves as modules.

An example is the bootstrap-dialog npm package (I have the bootstrap-switch and @types/bootstrap-switch packages installed). The @types does not export a module, but simply declares a namespace, and adds to the JQuery interface.
:  https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/bootstrap-switch/index.d.ts

In my app.ts I use it as such:

```
import {OtherClass} from './otherclass'

$(document).ready(()=>{ 
  let thisPage= new PageEntry ();
  thisPage.init();
}

class PageEntry {
  public init(): void {
    $('.bss').bootstrapSwitch();
    let x = new OtherClass();
   x.doSomething();
  }
}
```

But the output from webpack does not include bootstrapSwitch code. I tried adding:
`import * as BootstrapSwitch from 'bootstrap-switch';` but I obviously get an error stating that

> node_modules/@types/bootstrap-switch/index.d.ts' is not a module.

How do I ensure that bootstrap-switch gets pulled in?

I am using bootstrap-switch as an example, but I have about 5 packages with the same problem.

Comment: I have been able to get this to work with the following:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a file has no exports and is therefore imported for its side effects only (e.g. it augments `jQuery`), the correct way to import it in ECMAScript, and by extension TypeScript, is as follows

```
import 'bootstrap-switch';
```

A more complete example:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'bootstrap-switch';

$("[name='my-checkbox']").bootstrapSwitch();
```

Answer (score 0):

`import * as bs from 'bootstrap-switch';` gives an error of course because no module is exported.

However the following two lines worked for me... just not sure this is the best way to do it:

```
declare var require: any;
let bs = require('bootstrap-switch');
import {OtherClass} from './otherclass'
```

Hope this helps someone. Let me know if there is a better way.

Comment: The most definitely is a better way